# Access superclass Symbol.iterator

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

EDIT: loganmsmyth's answer is correct. The return type of my generator functions should be IterableIterator, but I'm leaving it as original written so the question makes sense.

Is it possible for a subclass to naturally consume the iterator of its superclass?

I can write this:

```
class Source {
    *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
        yield 0;
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
    }
}

class Filtered extends Source {
    constructor(private filter: (item: number) => boolean) {
        super();
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
        let it = super[Symbol.iterator]();
        for (let item = it.next(); !item.done; item = it.next()) {
            if (this.filter(item.value)) {
                yield item.value;
            }
        }
    }
}

let list = new Filtered(item => item % 2 == 0);
for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

But I'd rather not manually consume a naked iterator in `Filtered[Symbol.iterator]`, but instead write something like this (illegal):

```
    *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
        for (let item of super) {
            if (this.filter(item)) {
                yield item;
            }
        }
    }
```

FYI, this is Typescript 2.3 targeting ES5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the default iterator objects are also iterable, so you can do

```
*[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
    for (let item of super[Symbol.iterator]()) {
        if (this.filter(item)) {
            yield item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does indeed seem like a Typescript bug to me. Woops, you erased the comment with the error. Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Yeah, not sure what I screwed up when testing it, but when I tried again, it worked. The compiler still complained until I changed the return type of the generators to IterableIterator.  Works fine, thanks. :)